# Discord.Intents(32767) vs [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

Do you know why the "message sent" is displayed only with the first solution?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("bot is ready");
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    console.log("message sent");
});

client.login(config.token);
```

And not with this? (That is the example code on the discord.js documentation.)

```js
const config = require("./config.json");
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("bot is ready");
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  console.log("message sent");
});

client.login(config.token);
```

The bot is ready in both solutions, but I don't get why only in the first one when I send a message in the server the bot detects it, maybe because I don't know what does mean "32767".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `32767` means `ALL_INTENTS`. The `Intents` class extends a [`BitField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BitField). Meaning that you can represent all the intents you want via a single number by filling in specific bits of the bitfield.

According to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents), this is how each flag is represented by a bit shift.

```js
const ALL_INTENTS = 
    (1 << 0) +  // GUILDS
    (1 << 1) +  // GUILD_MEMBERS
    (1 << 2) +  // GUILD_BANS
    (1 << 3) +  // GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS
    (1 << 4) +  // GUILD_INTEGRATIONS
    (1 << 5) +  // GUILD_WEBHOOKS
    (1 << 6) +  // GUILD_INVITES
    (1 << 7) +  // GUILD_VOICE_STATES
    (1 << 8) +  // GUILD_PRESENCES
    (1 << 9) +  // GUILD_MESSAGES
    (1 << 10) + // GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    (1 << 11) + // GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING
    (1 << 12) + // DIRECT_MESSAGES
    (1 << 13) + // DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    (1 << 14);  // DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING

// Outputs 32767
console.log(ALL_INTENTS);
```

> Do you know why the "message sent" is displayed only with the first solution?

Because in the second solution, you are missing `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent to receive the `messageCreate` event.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark.